# Conversion warnings for std::copy and std::vector::assign

Tags: c++

When a floating point number is inserted into a `std::vector<int>`, the number must be converted by some kind of rounding. Typically this changes the number, 1.5 is changed to 1 or 2, and I would expect the compiler at least to warn about this conversion. So I use the `-Wconversion` flag on g++ or clang++. This enables warnings for `std::vector::push_back` or direct assignment, but not for `std::copy` or `std::vector::assign(iterator first, iterator end)`.

Now my question is: How do I get conversion warnings for `std::copy` and `std::vector::assign`?

Here is my example program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using source_type = std::vector<double>;
using target_type = std::vector<int>;

int main() {
    source_type vsource;
    target_type vtarget1;
    target_type vtarget2;
    target_type vtarget3;
    target_type vtarget4;

    // Fill source with a number
    vsource.push_back(1.5);

    // This will give a compiler warning as expected
    vtarget1.push_back(vsource.at(0));

    // This does not give a warning, why not?
    vtarget2.assign(vsource.begin(), vsource.end());

    // Also this does not give a warning, why not?
    vtarget3.assign(vsource.size(), 0);
    std::copy(vsource.begin(), vsource.end(), vtarget3.begin());


    // The following should be equivalent to std::copy according to
    // http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/?kw=copy
    // Here we get a warning as expected (in contrast to std::copy).
    vtarget4.assign(vsource.size(), 0);
    auto source = vsource.begin();
    auto target = vtarget4.begin();
    while (source != vsource.end()) {
       *target = *source;
       ++target; ++source;
    }

    std::cout << vsource.at(0)  << " "
              << vtarget1.at(0) << " "
              << vtarget2.at(0) << " "
              << vtarget3.at(0) << " "
              << vtarget4.at(0) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I compile with:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c++11 -pedantic 
clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c++11 -pedantic
```

I only get two warnings, I want to have a few more:

```
question.cpp:22:24: warning: implicit conversion turns floating-point number into integer: 'value_type' (aka 'double')
      to 'value_type' (aka 'int') [-Wfloat-conversion]
    vtarget1.push_back(vsource.at(0));

question.cpp:40:18: warning: implicit conversion turns floating-point number into integer: 'double' to 'int'
      [-Wfloat-conversion]
       *target = *source;
```

Comment: read up on `-Wsystem-headers`

Comment: @o11c Ok, with `-Wsystem-headers` I think I see the warning on `std::copy(vsource.begin(), vsource.end(), vtarget3.begin());`, but I don't see a warning on `vtarget2.assign(vsource.begin(), vsource.end());`. Unfortunately there are too many other warnings as well. If this would be the way to go, I'm lost :(

Comment: @Pates You don't see a warning for `assign` because (in libstdc++ at least), `std::vector::assign` ends up calling `std::copy` to copy the data in this case.  Therefore there's only one place to warn about the conversion.

Comment: Use [`-Wfloat-conversion`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html). It is documented at [3.8 Options to Request or Suppress Warnings](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) in the GCC manual. (Why `-Wall -Wextra` or `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion` does not enable it is a different matter).

Comment: Specifically, it ends up going via `assign` -> `_M_assign_dispatch` -> `_M_assign_aux`  -> `_M_allocate_and_copy` -> depending on current size/capacity, `std::copy` and/or `std::__uninitialized_copy_a` -> `std::uninitialized_copy` -> `std::__uninitialized_copy<false>::__uninit_copy` -> `std::copy`. So there are, statically, 4 calls to `std::copy`.

Comment: @jww The warning message which I receive with `-Wconversion` indicates that this already includes `-Wfloat-conversion`. And indeed, `-Wconversion` and `-Wfloat-conversion` give/miss the same warnings.

Comment: @o11c This seems convincing. But why does `std::vector::push_back` give a warning without `-Wsystem-headers`? Does `#include <algorithm>` include a "system header", and `#include <vector>` does not?

Comment: `push_back` is specified as taking a `int`, so the conversion happens in your code. But try `emplace_back`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following flags `-std=c++11  -Wfloat-conversion -Wsystem-headers` to make GCC additionally at least warn for this LOC as well

```
std::copy(vsource.begin(), vsource.end(), vtarget3.begin());
```

as well as you can see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/wgLNaE).

The output is then

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':

<source>:21:34: warning: conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<double>, double>::value_type' {aka 'double'} to 'std::vector<int>::value_type' {aka 'int'} may change value [-Wfloat-conversion]

21 |     vtarget1.push_back(vsource.at(0));

   |                        ~~~~~~~~~~^~~

<source>:38:18: warning: conversion from 'double' to 'int' may change value [-Wfloat-conversion]

38 |        *target = *source;

   |                  ^~~~~~~

In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20180917/include/c++/9.0.0/bits/char_traits.h:39,

                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20180917/include/c++/9.0.0/ios:40,

                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20180917/include/c++/9.0.0/ostream:38,

                 from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20180917/include/c++/9.0.0/iostream:39,

                 from <source>:1:

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20180917/include/c++/9.0.0/bits/stl_algobase.h: In instantiation of 'static _OI std::__copy_move<false, false, std::random_access_iterator_tag>::__copy_m(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = double*; _OI = int*]':

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20180917/include/c++/9.0.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:400:30:   required from '_OI std::__copy_move_a(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = double*; _OI = int*]'

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20180917/include/c++/9.0.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:437:30:   required from '_OI std::__copy_move_a2(_II, _II, _OI) [with bool _IsMove = false; _II = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double> >; _OI = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >]'

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20180917/include/c++/9.0.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:470:7:   required from '_OI std::copy(_II, _II, _OI) [with _II = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<double*, std::vector<double> >; _OI = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int> >]'

<source>:28:63:   required from here

/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20180917/include/c++/9.0.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:338:18: warning: conversion from 'double' to 'int' may change value [-Wfloat-conversion]

338 |        *__result = *__first;

    |                  ^

Compiler returned: 0
```

As for clang: This flag set is rather verbose and not really giving more insight.

Comment: Thanks for trying out and for pointing me to the godbolt page, but the warnings in your answer refer to `vector::push_back` and the direct assignment `*target = *source;`, not to `std::copy`, as already mentioned in the question.

Comment: Doesnt it say from source line 28 which is std::copy... Sorry, cannot look it up atm

Comment: I also see the `assign` warning if I comment the `copy` line. So your answer at least gives me a way to search specifically for this kind of error. It is not a satisfying solution for my underlying problem, but it answers the question.