# gcc strange behaviour on abs function

Tags: c++, gcc

I ported some code from windows (vs2010) to gcc

a piece of it looks like:

```
double r1 /* = some value */;
double r2 /* = some value */;
double diff = abs(r1-r2);
std::cerr<<  r1 << ", " << r2 << ", " << diff<< std::endl;
```

it compiles on gcc (arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ (Raspbian 6.3.0-18+rpi1+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516) with `-Wall -Wextra` without warnings.

The result is:

```
0.121, 0.0709839, 0
0.015, 0.131958, 0
0.015, 0.00799561, 0
0.21, 0.00799561, 0
0.182, 0.205994, 0
0.015, 0.00799561, 0
```

On windows the result is correct. There are double-overloads on the `abs` functions.

I am not `using namespace std;`. It seems that under gcc these overloads does not exist in global namespace.

I do not know what exactly the standard says, but i would have expected at least a warning about the double->int-conversion on passing the the difference to the `abs` function.

Do i have something missed? Why do i not get this warning?

Comment: There are no warnings about implicit conversions in C++. There are no overloads of `abs` for integer values, consider `fabs` instead (if you wish to avoid using the STL for some reason.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/abs You might want to type `std::` before your `abs`.

Comment: Funny enough, if you `#include <math.h>` instead of `<cmath>` it works properly. Apparently `math.h` brings everything into global namespace, while `cmath` selectively brings a single overload. Huh.

Comment: @bipll yes, this was the mistake, since with vs2010 the overload does exists I got the wrong results - but the main question is, why gcc does not warn about the conversion - even with `-Wall` and `-Wextra`

Comment: gcc is known to be far worse than clang when it comes to reliable warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for the compiler option `-Wfloat-conversion` or, more general, `-Wconversion`. Then g++ gives me this warning:

```
 warning: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘double’ may alter its value [-Wfloat-conversion]
     double diff = abs(r1-r2);
```

None of the two options is included in `-Wall` or `-Wextra`.

It works as long as the conversion is in your code, see [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52375445/10377098)

Comment: Be aware that `-Wconversion` is triggered by all conversions, so lots of false positives to be expected.

Answer (score 10):

`abs` is a C function that takes one integer and returns another integer.

You want to use the C++ version `std::abs` instead. Clang would actually warn about the mistake (I even turn it into an error `-Werror=absolute-value`), not sure if there is a similar flag for gcc (not warning about all conversions, just for `abs`).